# ¿Cómo validar variables no declaradas y sesiones - PHP?

Tags: php

Existen errores comunes cuando se trata de enviar información en la misma página y estos errores son normales por lo que no están declaradas o su valor es `NULO`

Entonces como sabemos que no es un error grave y que es un error normal por lo que no están declaradas o su valor es nulo, una simple solución es desactivar los error de advertencia entre otros.

```
error_reporting(0);
```

Aunque es una solución, para mi no es correcto su uso desactivar los errores, el código debe ser validado primeramente.

> Si es bueno su uso pero primeramente que todo código sea valido y luego usarlos por futuras actualizaciones y así evitar mostrar errores al visitante o mostrar algún error que un Hacker pueda obtener provecho de aquel error.

**El siguiente ejemplo:**

Cuando se pierde la información enviada por método `post`

```
$unpost = $_POST['post'];
echo $unpost;
```

Muestra este mensaje de error: `Notice: Undefined index: post`

Otro error similar es cuando se trata de mostrar un dato especifico cuando existe un `SESSION` de algún dato:

```
if( $_SESSION['datos']['radio'] == $key ) { else {}}
```

¿Cómo puedo validar correctamente las variables no declaradas y sesiones vacías al perderse por algún motivo o razón?

**Ejemplo dinámico:**

```
<?php
    $r =array(
        1 => 'Opcione Uno',
    2 => 'Opcione Dos',
    3 => 'Opcion Tres',
    );

    // recorremos las opciones del radio button
    // comprobamos si se selecciono antes una opción comparando los key
    echo'<form method="POST" action="a.php">';
    foreach ($r as $key => $value) {
        // para recuperar los datos de un radio button
      if( $_SESSION['datos_form']['radio'] == $key ) {
        echo '<input name="radio" type="radio" id="'.$key.'" value="'.$key.'"  checked="checked" >';
        echo '<label for="'.$key.'" title="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</label>';
      } else {
        echo '<input name="radio" type="radio" id="'.$key.'" value="'.$key.'" >';
        echo '<label for="'.$key.'" title="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</label>';
      }
    }
  echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>';



if ($_POST["radio"] == 1) {
    //Confirmacion($_POST["radio"]);
  echo "<p>Has elegido Opcion uno</p>";
}

if ($_POST["radio"] == 2) {
    //Confirmacion($_POST["radio"]);
    echo "<p>Has elegido Opcion dos</p>";
}

if ($_POST["radio"] == 3) {
    //Confirmacion($_POST["radio"]);
    echo "<p>Has elegido Opcion tres</p>";
}

$unpost = $_POST['post'];
echo $unpost;
```

Comment: `isset($_POST['post'])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primero hay que tener en cuenta $_POST,$_GET,$_SESSION y $_COOKIE sin **arreglos** y aunque son globales pueden tratarse como cualquier arreglo.

El error que comentas es el resultado de usar un elemento de un arreglo que no esta definido.

En php la definición de variables no es necesaria como en otros lenguajes de programación. Por lo que se puede usar una variable sin haberla definido anteriormente pero el valor por defecto sera el de valor por defecto resultante del **cast**.

Aun que no es necesario es una buena practica de programación validar que los variables estén definidas antes de usarlas.

Te recomiendo no usar las variables globales directamente en el cuerpo de tu script puedes asignarlo a una variable y usar esta en su lugar.

```
$P = $_POST;
$S = $_SESSION;


$radio = isset($P['radio']) ? $P['radio'] : -1;
$radio = intval($radio);
$datosForm = (isset($S['datos_form']) && is_array($S['datos_form'])) ? $S['datos_form']  : array ();
```

$unpost = isset($P['post']) ? $P['post'] : '';

De esta forma incluso si deseas depurar o cambiar de $_POST a $_GET solo necesitas cambiar la asignación `$P = $_POST;` por `$P = $_GET;` y todo tu código se mantiene funcional Y tendras un mejor control de lo que recibes.

Para el caso de matrices multidimensionales deberás validar la existencia de cada dimensión antes de llegar a la dimensión final por ejemplo:

```
// Para validar.
$S['d1']['d2'][d3]['d4'] = 'x';
//deberas validar cada dimensión:
if (isset($S['d1']) &&
    isset($S['d1']['d2']) &&
    isset($S['d1']['d2']['d3']) &&
    isset($S['d1']['d2']['d3']['d4']) &&
) {
    echo $S['d1']['d2']['d3']['d4'];
}
```

Aquí mi edición de tu código para hacer mas clara la explicacion:

```
<?php

/* En:
*
*  $P = $_POST;
*
* podemos poner $_GET,$_COOKIES
* o para depurar hasta:
*
* $P = array(
*   'radio' => 1,
*   'post' => ''
* );
*
*
* Lo mismo aplica para:
* $S = $_SESSION;
*/

$P = $_POST;
$S = $_SESSION;


$radio = isset($P['radio']) ? $P['radio'] : -1;
$radio = intval($radio);
/* Nos aseguramos que el indice datos_form este definido y sea un arreglo */
$datosForm = (isset($S['datos_form']) && is_array($S['datos_form'])) ? $S['datos_form']  : array ();
$unpost = isset($P['post']) ? $P['post'] : '';




$r =array(
  1 => 'Opcione Uno',
  2 => 'Opcione Dos',
  3 => 'Opcion Tres',
);

    // recorremos las opciones del radio button
    // comprobamos si se selecciono antes una opción comparando los key
echo'<form method="POST" action="a.php">';

foreach ($r as $key => $value) {
    // para recuperar los datos de un radio button
  if( isset($datosForm['radio']) && $datosForm['radio'] == $key ) {

    echo '<input name="radio" type="radio" id="'.$key.'" value="'.$key.'"  checked="checked" >';
    echo '<label for="'.$key.'" title="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</label>';

  } else {

    echo '<input name="radio" type="radio" id="'.$key.'" value="'.$key.'" >';
    echo '<label for="'.$key.'" title="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</label>';
  }
}

echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>';


switch($radio) {

  case 1:
    echo "<p>Has elegido Opcion uno</p>";
  break;

  case 2:
    echo "<p>Has elegido Opcion dos</p>";
  break;
  case 1:
    echo "<p>Has elegido Opcion tres</p>";
  break;
  default:
    echo "<p>Opcion no valida/p>";
  break;
}


echo $unpost;
```

Comment: es una buena practica ahora mismo reviso esta pregunta es [fuente de esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/96689/cómo-validar-datos-del-proceso-wizard-con-php) para que tengas una mayor idea.

Comment: [Nota de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php) Es recomendable evitar el "apilamiento" expresiones ternarias. El comportamiento de PHP al utilizar más de un operador ternario en una única sentencia no es evidente.

Comment: Tu observación es correcta por ello uso los paréntesis.

Comment: @SergioCauich Existe un error Notice: Undefined index: datos_form in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\index.php on line 10 `$datosForm = isset($S['datos_form']) ? $S['datos_form'] : ( is_array($S['datos_form']) ? $S['datos_form'] : array ());`

Comment: Es correcto  la parte entre paréntesis va en el caso verdadero y la parte falsa quedaría solo con array()

Answer (score 0):

> ¿Cómo puedo validar correctamente las variables no declaradas y
>   sesiones vacías al perderse por algún motivo o razón?

Puedes usar para validar el método [**isset()**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php) que devuelve un valor `true` si la variable existe, de otra forma retorna `false`.

Ejemplo:

```
if (isset($_POST['post']) { 
  //Existe valor
  $unpost = $_POST['post'] 
}else{
  //No existe valor 
}
```

> [**isset()**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php) — Determina si una variable está definida y no es NULL

en cuanto al array podrías usar [**empty()**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php) para validar si tiene algún valor:

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['datos']['radio'])) 
{   
   //Existe valor
}else{
   //No existe valor
}
```

Comment: en el primer ejemplo es lo ideal pero no esta validado correctamente el código existe errores observa [https://ideone.com/gfBfwU](https://ideone.com/gfBfwU) y en el `array` y el resto de su contenido como lo validas?

Comment: @J.Doe  
Agregué una actualización pero veo tu ejemplo en ideone, no tiene nada!

Comment: en la parte de abajo puedes visualizar el error: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/jKLGlu/prog.php on line 3` y se supone que es ahí donde se tiene que ejecutar el `else` cuando no existe `post` recibido

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza el método isset para variables no declaradas: http://php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php

Puedes usar empty también, aunque en este caso evalúa también variables vacias: http://php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php